# Grade Check java

Tags: java

I wrote this program to convert a number grade into a letter grade but I keep getting the  same errors. Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
import static java.lang.System.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Grade
{
private int numGrade;
 public Grade()
{
Grade test;
 }
public void setGrade(int grade)
{ 
numGrade = grade;
 if (grade >= 90)
{
 System.out.println("A");
 }
{
System.out.println("B");
}
public String getLetterGrade( ) {
  String letGrade="A";
 if (grade>= 90)
{
return letGrade;
}
public String toString(){
return numGrade + " is a " + getLetterGrade() + "\n";
} 
}
```

Comment: I suggest you fix the code so it compiles. I also suggest you only add code you actually need. You can delete half of it

Answer (score 1):

The syntax used is incorrect.

Attached is a sample code to do the conversion

```
public class Grade {
    private int numGrade;

    public void setGrade(int grade) {
        numGrade = grade;
        if (grade >= 90) {
            System.out.println("A");
        } else {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }

    public String getLetterGrade() {
        String letGrade = "B";
        if (numGrade >= 90) {
            return "A";
        }
        return letGrade;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return numGrade + " is a " + getLetterGrade() + "\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you tried to attack the same thing from many different positions.
first of lets start with converting numerical grades into letter grades, so before engaging to inputs, start with asking the kind of grade the user wishes to convert

```
    char choise;
    choise = reader.nextChar(); //ask for N or L for numerical or letter
```

next i'll show a sample code for letter to numerical convertion

```
   public int getNGrade(char grade)
   { 
        if (grade == 'A')
             return 90;
        else if (grade == 'B')
             return 80; //and so on
   }
```

same way can be used for the numerical to letter convertion

in the main class u call the function:

```
    charGrade = reader.nextChar();
    System.out.println("Your grade in numbers is " + getNGrade(charGrade));
```

i'm guessing that's what u meant, hope i was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be this and it works perfectly:

```
public class Grade {

   private int numGrade;

   public Grade(int grade) {
        numGrade = grade;
   }

   public int getGrade() {
       return numGrade;
   }

   public void setGrade(int grade) {
        numGrade = grade;
   }

   public String getLetterGrade() {
       if(numGrade <0 || numGrade > 100) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such a grade!");

       else if(numGrade>=90) return "A";

       else if (numGrade >= 80) return "B";

       else if(numGrade >= 70) return "C";

       else if(numGrade >= 60) return "D";

       else return "F";

   }

   public String toString(){
        return numGrade + " is a " + getLetterGrade() + "\n";
   } 
}
```

You can include in the same class a main method or create a separate class for testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Grade g = new Grade(75);   //you can enter the grade manually or simply using a Scanner object
    System.out.println(g);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Tutorial {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     // calling Scanner method
        String restart = "Y";               //initialising the restart variable
        while (restart.equals("Y"))             // testing the conditon(if Y is equals then it continues)
        {
            int grade;
            System.out.println("WELCOME TO ABD GRADING SYSTEM.");           
            System.out.println("Enter your Score(between 1 - 100) : ");                 // Displaying a message on screen
            grade = input.nextInt();                            // Accept Input from the user
            if(grade<=39)
                System.out.println("Your grade is F9");
                else if(grade==40 || grade<=49)
                    System.out.println("Your grade is D7");
            else if(grade==50 || grade<=59)
                System.out.println("Your grade is C6");
            else if(grade==60 || grade<=69)
                System.out.println("Your grade is C5");
            else if(grade==70 || grade<=79)
                System.out.println("Your grade is B2");
            else if(grade==80 || grade<=100)
                System.out.println("Your grade is A1");
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Input Correct score between (1 - 100).");
            }
            System.out.println("THANK YOU.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to Calculate again? Y/N ");
            restart = input.next();
        }
    }       
}
```